# xhci_hcp module constantly detecting devices

Tags: drivers, usb, hardware, pci

**Problem**

I want to start getting into GPGPU work, so I got an ASUS Rampage IV Black Edition gaming motherboard.  I thought it would support multiple GPUs well.  However, I have had nothing but trouble with the xhci_hcd module.  It just fills up my `dmesg` output with lines like this:

```
<some stuff> usb 1-1: new high-speed USB deice number 1 using xhci_hcd
<some stuff> usb 1-1: new high-speed USB deice number 2 using xhci_hcd
...
<some stuff> usb 1-1: new high-speed USB deice number 127 using xhci_hcd
<some stuff> usb 1-1: new high-speed USB deice number 1 using xhci_hcd
...
```

Also, it causes any USB hardware detection to stall.  This happens while running `lsusb`, or during boot, or any hardware detection steps of installation (during installation, I ran `rmmod xhci_hcp` to get around that).  I can usually interrupt these scanning operations (and make them work right) by unplugging my usb keyboard or something.

**Current Workaround**

By running:

```
echo "0000:06:00.0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
```

I can eliminate the "always detecting a new device" problem, and "hanging on hardware scan" problem.  However, I also lose 4 of my 8 USB3.0 ports.

**What I need help with**

Is anybody familiar with this problem, and they know exactly how to fix it?  If not:

Is there some option I can hand to `modprobe xhci_hcd` that might make it work properly?  Where do I even find the different options to try them?

Does the BIOS of my motherboard affect how the `xhci_hcd` performs after the OS has actually started?  Or does the BIOS change how the actual USB device operates after the OS has started?  If so, what sort of options should I look at changing?

**My Setup**

Processor: i7-4930k

Motherboard: Asus Rampage IV Black Edition

Linux: Debian 8.2.0 (Jessie), netinstall

`lspci | grep USB` output:

```
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 06)
06:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
0b:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
0e:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
```

`lsmod | grep hci` output:

```
ahci     33291  2
libahci  27158  1 ahci
ehci_pci 12512  0
xhci_hcd 148881 0
libata   177457 2 ahci,libahci
usbcore  195430 6 btusb,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,xhci_hcd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by disabling Asmedia USB3.0 controller USB3_E12 and USB3_E34 in the BIOS. Not a perfect fix but well enough for me.

Advanced > Onboard Devices Configuration

Asmedia USB 3.0 Controller (USB3_E12 USB3_E34) > Disabled

Comment: Finally got around to testing this... it seems to have a similar effect as what I was doing except my fix only worked after login.  Your fix saves the OS from dealing with that mess every boot.  Side note: I noticed the peculiar effect that I had to move my keyboard from one of the USB2.0 ports to a USB3.0 port in order to use it with the UEFI.  I should also mention that my main workaround for the lost ports was installing a USB3.0 PCI card.